# Enforce minimum wait time for next thread after the lock has been released?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, thread-safety, locking

I am making requests to a webservice, that has 200ms minimum wait time between requests. I want to enforce this policy in my multi-thread application. Currently I have this code in my application:

```
lock.lock();
String resp = httpUtility.makeGetRequest(serviceUrl); //make request to service
lock.unlock() //timer should start after thread exits this
```

If a single thread comes here I want it to pass immediately. If the thread exits `lock.unlock()` then I want it to start a timer of 200ms. During that time no thread should get past `lock.lock()`.

I also want the queue to be fair, so I can't just use `wait()` and `notify()`. On the other hand `Lock` is no good either because only the acquiring thread can release the `Lock`, and I don't want to stall the thread for 200ms.

What would be a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `while (true)` cycle which would execute each new request in a separate thread and then sleep for 200ms, e.g. something like

```
try {
    while (true) {
        executor.execute(requestQueue.take());
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Artyom's answer is a good one, but I am reading your question to mean that you have several threads that would want to make a GET request.

In that case, create a RequestHandler class that implements Runnable, eg is thread itself. Have each worker thread get the singleton instance of this RequestHandler class. Something like:

```
RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
new Thread(requestHandler).start(); //your one and only of this class
```

Then, create a simple list/queue in the RequestHandler. When a Worker creates a new request, it simply queues up a request:

```
class RequestHandler implements Runnable {

    List<String> requestUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void submitRequest(String url) {
        System.out.println("===>Request incoming for " + url);
        requestUrls.add(url);
    }
```

Now, add your run method to process the queue as requests come in. Take the oldest url off the queue, make the request, then sleep for 200ms.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            String currentRequestUrl = null;
            if (!requestUrls.isEmpty()) {
                currentRequestUrl = requestUrls.remove(0);
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);  //give CPU a break
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

            if (currentRequestUrl != null) {
                System.out.println("##Simulating calling " + currentRequestUrl);
                System.out.println("##Request to " + currentRequestUrl + " is complete.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So now, every time you create a Worker, make sure you pass it this "singleton" RequestHandler.

```
class Worker implements Runnable {

    private String url;
    private RequestHandler requestHandler;

    Worker(String url, RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        this.url = url;
        this.requestHandler = requestHandler;
    }
```

and when the worker is ready to submit a request, it invokes the RequestHandler

```
    requestHandler.submitRequest(url);
```